# Go to parent component in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

Basically the title. Does WebStorm have an option to jump to parent component? For example, you are editing `child-component.ts` and you need to jump to `parent-component.ts` to change some input value. Or you are in `child-component.html` and you need to jump to `parent-component.html`

Jumping from parent to child is super helpful.

Comment: no, there is no way to do this

Answer (score 2):

Note that there might several parent components for a given react component, so I assume you want something like "Find all usages for a given child react component"

If so, the following should work:

1. Use "Previous Method" hotkey (Alt+Up on Windows)
2. Use "Find Usages" hotkey (Alt+F7 on Windows)

Alternative for step 2 is to use "Goto" shortcut (Ctrl+B on Windows), which is similar to pressing Ctrl+LeftClick.

I tried it on WebStorm on Windows and it worked correctly for React